# Cloud Run /Cloud Code deployment error in intellij

Tags: google-cloud-platform, minikube, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-code

trying to follow the [Getting Started instructions](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/quickstart-cloud-run) for Deploying a Cloud Run service with Cloud Code  in Intellij (deploying HelloWorld Flask app container with `Cloud Run: Deploy`) but getting the following error, any idea why this might be happening

it worked initially i.e. deployed the app on Cloud Run service using the same steps, and then started throwing this error after a week or so when trying to redeploy, there was no change in project settings.

intellij and docker versions are the latest.

authenticated to google cloud project with `gcloud auth login --update-adc`

The local run works fine (`Cloud Run: Run Locally`),

but running the `Cloud Run: Deploy`  throws this "code 89" error

```
Preparing Google Cloud SDK (this may take several minutes for first time setup)...

Creating skaffold file: /var/.../skaffold8013155926954225609.tmp

Configuring image push settings in /var/.../skaffold8013155926954225609.tmp


../Library/Application Support/cloud-code/bin/versions/../
  skaffold build --filename /var/.../skaffold8013155926954225609.tmp --tag latest --skip-tests=true

invalid skaffold config: getting minikube env: 
running [/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
  minikube docker-env --shell none -p minikube --user=skaffold]

 - stdout: "false exit code 89"
 - stderr: ""
 - cause: exit status 89

 Failed to build and push Cloud Run container image. 
 Please ensure your builder settings are correct, network is available, you are logged in to a valid GCP project, and try again.
```

Edit: I see minikube error code 89: [ExGuestUnavailable](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/contrib/errorcodes/) and it's an error code specific to the guest host, still unclear what might be causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with skaffold attempting to communicate with minikube (which could be used for building images as well). Please try cleaning minikube

```
minikube stop
minikube delete --all --purge
```

and try again.

Comment: minikube : The term 'minikube' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i still don't know why it fails to deploy to cloud run from intellij but i got it to deploy from command line

```
cd my-flask-app

#step 1: build container image from Dockerfile and submit to container registry
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/my-flask-app

#step 2: deploy the image on cloud run (reference) 
gcloud run deploy --image  gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/my-flask-app
```

references:

- https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers
  https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart

Edit: the answer above did the trick : `minikube delete --all --purge`